# Angular tags directive issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [pretty nice plugin](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api) which provides **tags input directive for AngularJS**.

I'm using the parameter `onTagAdding` to check tag's value before it will be added to input.

```
on-tag-adding="{expression}"
```

So, as documentation says:

> Expression to evaluate that will be invoked before adding a new tag. 
>   The  new tag is available as $tag. This method must return either true or false. If false, the tag will not be added.

So here is an [live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/E51PmBvUNLuW4aDWGR5l?p=preview).

```
$scope.checkTag = function(tag) {
     angular.forEach($scope.forbiddenTags, function(e){
        if (e.text === tag.text) {
            alert('Tag is forbidden')
            return false;
        }
     })

     alert('Execution is continuing');
}
```

I'm expecting that if entered value matches one for those tags from `$scope.forbiddenTags` array, then *false* should be returned and function's execution should be stopped, but it works not like i am expecting =). I have tried just with *return* but it doesn't work either.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that returning from forEach iterator function is of no use, it wont ultimately return that return value from the outer checkTag function as you expected. You can try something like this.

```
$scope.checkTag = function(tag) {
 var found = $scope.forbiddenTags.some(function(ftag){
    if (ftag.text === tag.text) {
        alert('Tag is forbidden');
        return true;
    }
    //If you do not need alert then just do 
    // return (ftag.text === tag.text);
 });
 return !found;
}
```

I am using [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (check out the shim if need to support IE < 9) here so that i exit out of looping through once a match is found (to avoid unnecessary iteration which you cannot do with `forEach`) while returning boolean value. You could instead use a traditional `for` loop as use return as well. If you want to still use forEach then save a boolean flag is it is found and return it outside.

```
$scope.checkTag = function(tag) {
     var found = false;
     angular.forEach($scope.forbiddenTags, function(e){
        if (e.text === tag.text) {
            alert('Tag is forbidden')
            found  = true;
            //A return here is of no use as it will not break out of the loop
        }
     });

     alert('Execution is continuing');
     return !found; //If found is true then return false and vice versa
}
```

Comment: Cool! It works like a charm=) Thanks for an answer and good explanation!

Comment: @user3673623 You are welcome. :) Note:- You can also use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ,[Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with Shim support, but `array.some` would be more precise for this.

Comment: @PSL Nice explanation regarding IE>9 support:)